# Problema routes Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, api

He creado un servicio de autenticación con el namespace, sin embargo al tratar de llamarlo me arroja un error: NotFoundHttpException ¿Alguien tiene idea de por qué?

```html
namespace App\Http\Controllers\AthenticationOrders;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Helpers\CurrentClient;
use Inggema\Core\Http\Response\ResponseBuilder;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class AthenticationOrdersController extends Controller
{

    public function authenticate(Request $request) {
        .......
    }
}
```

En mi archivo de rutas api.php tengo lo siguiente:

```html
<?php

use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'authOrder',
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthenticationOrders\AthenticationOrdersController@authenticate');
});
```

No me funciona obtengo esto siempre:

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
in RouteCollection.php line 179

Gracias a quien me pueda apoyar.

Comment: Estas ingresando a api/authOrder/login ?